# Как быть, если название радиостанции соседствует с названием передачи?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Это название главы из редактируемой книги (контекста нет по определению):

> Программа радиостанции Эхо Москвы «Мамочки-мамаши».

«Эхо Москвы» требует своих кавычек, и что со всем этим кавычечным изобилием делать?

Я не перевру смысл, если предложу:

*Радиостанция «Эхо Москвы». Программа* (или ***передача*** - это существенно?) *«Мамочки-мамаши».*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, программа и передача могут считаться сининимами. ([Мамочки-мамаши](https://echo.msk.ru/programs/mamashi/), https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Мой вариант:

**Программа «Мамочки-мамаши» радиостанции «Эхо Москвы».**